# Unfamiliar SQL UPDATE statement for running total solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I came across the following SQL UPDATE statement that calculates a running total column in a table:

```
UPDATE N1 SET
    RunningTotal = (SELECT SUM (SubTotal)
                    FROM #Sales X1
                    WHERE
                        N1.FiscalYear = X1.FiscalYear AND
                        X1.OrderNumber <= N1.OrderNumber)
FROM
    #Sales N1
```

I have not seen this type of pattern before, and because of the difficulty involved in searching for SQL statements, I have not been able to find an explanation.  Specifically, I'd like to know how the above statement is able to update the entire table; how is the looping happening?

Note: The statement works fine; the before and after results as seen in SSMS is as follows:

[image]

(I am using SQL Server 2017 Community edition on Windows 10 x64.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really looping, but I'll explain:

```
UPDATE N1 SET
    RunningTotal = ...
FROM #Sales N1
```

It's updating the whole table because of this. There is no where clause on the update, so every single row will be updated no matter what. I personally prefer this style of aliasing the table and using UPDATE against the alias because when you have complicated updates, it can make viewing the change easier.

The inner part:

```
SELECT SUM (SubTotal)
FROM #Sales X1
WHERE N1.FiscalYear = X1.FiscalYear AND
   X1.OrderNumber <= N1.OrderNumber
```

Gets the sum for of sales amounts each year prior to and equal to the order being processed. It isn't looping in code; it's really running a subquery per row or data being returned.

Comment: **"There is no where clause on the update, so every single row will be updated no matter what."** That was the key information missing in my little brain.  Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement simply sum all rows before current OrderNumber.

Let me show you another approach:

> ```
> create table tbl (FiscalYear int, OrderDate date, OrderNumber int, SubTotal decimal(10,2), RunningTotal decimal(10,2));
> insert into tbl values
> (2011, '20110531', 1, 5000.02, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 2, 1000.15, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 3,  700.25, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 4,  225.02, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 5, 1258.25, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 6, 1000.00, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 7,  695.20, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 8,  789.25, null),
> (2011, '20110531', 9, 2125.02, null);
> GO
> ```

The CTE query calculates cumulative totals and second one update your table.

> ```
> ;with x as 
> (
>     select FiscalYear,
>            OrderDate,
>            OrderNumber,
>            SubTotal,
>            sum(SubTotal) over (partition by FiscalYear 
>                                order by FiscalYear, OrderDate, OrderNumber) as CumTotal
>     from   tbl
> )
> update t
> set    RunningTotal = CumTotal
> from   tbl t
> join   x
> on     x.Fiscalyear = t.FiscalYear
> and    x.OrderDate = t.OrderDate
> and    x.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 9 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from tbl;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> FiscalYear | OrderDate           | OrderNumber | SubTotal | RunningTotal
> ---------: | :------------------ | ----------: | :------- | :-----------
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           1 | 5000.02  | 5000.02     
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           2 | 1000.15  | 6000.17     
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           3 | 700.25   | 6700.42     
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           4 | 225.02   | 6925.44     
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           5 | 1258.25  | 8183.69     
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           6 | 1000.00  | 9183.69     
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           7 | 695.20   | 9878.89     
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           8 | 789.25   | 10668.14    
>       2011 | 31/05/2011 00:00:00 |           9 | 2125.02  | 12793.16
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=77c37126616ee5dd91414bb8e02caa64)*

Comment: I really, really appreciate your answer.  Can we say that the explicit JOIN in your approach corresponds to the implicit join in the SELECT statement in my question?  Or is your approach totally different?  Also, how does the looping happen in the original statement?  Is it just a result of the implicit join?  Thank you again.

Comment: It is barely different, first calculate cumulative total and then update the table.

Comment: Maybe you could generate a temporary table in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to your problem is an updatable CTE:

```
WITH toupdate AS 
      (SELECT S.*,
              SUM(SubTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY FiscalYear ORDER BY OrderNumber) AS new_RunningTotal
         FROM #Sales S
      )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET RunningTotal = new_RunningTotal;
```

This has no joins or correlated subqueries.  In general, window functions are going to be much faster than the correlated subquery equivalent.  Updatable CTEs are a very nice feature of SQL Server that saves you from an additional `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you.  Unnecessary JOINs are expensive, right?

Comment: @Sabuncu . . . In general, unnecessary joins are more expensive than queries without them.

Comment: I tried out your solution.  The Sales table contains 31K rows.  My original code takes about 45 seconds on my system (Ryzen 5 2400G).  Your solution, on same table, is instantaneous, **takes zero seconds!** :)  
Since my question was about understanding the original SQL statement, I am going to leave my answer pick as is, but if you'd like, I can post a different question where I can ask "how can you optimize this SQL statement" and wait for your answer.  Please let me know.  Thank you